# Does a 1 second datastore transaction limit applies only on a while group entity?

Tags: jquery, python, json, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to plot data retrieved from my **Tracking** ndb module.

```
class Tracking(ndb.Module):
    usrId = ndb.StringProperty()
    when= ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    score= ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Want to use a JsonProperty for Tracking module with key=When and Value=Score and process the result query within a Jquery plotting module.
Am I using the right property? 
what is  the database latency in case the number of queries soars? 
Does the 1 second limit used  is applied only only on a group entity or on the whole model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 second limit is 1 write transaction per entity group per second. So you may write to the same Kind at a much higher rate:

> The supported limit is one update per second per entity group outside transactions, or one transaction per second per entity group. If you aggregate multiple updates into one transaction, then you are limited to a maximum transaction size of 10 MB and the maximum write rate of Datastore server.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore#h.8yrg89iapdjp